# How to configure IIS to include sub-resources in its cache invalidation check?

Tags: .net, iis, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

TL;DR
I'm hosting a .NET site in IIS that serves images. When I update an image file without changing its filename, the old image continues to be displayed because the index.html itself is cached, and the updated image isn't recognized. I've found a workaround by appending a query parameter to the image URLs, but I'm exploring a better solution using IIS's cache settings to handle this caching issue.

---

I'm hosting a .NET MVC site in IIS which contains an index.html file with several `<img>` tags. The images are fetched from a folder on the web server where the site is hosted.

When I update an image (keeping the same filename), the browser continues to display the old image even though the actual file on disk has changed. If I navigate directly to the image URL, I can see the updated version, but the old version is shown when I refresh index.html.

From the network tab in Chrome DevTools, I can see that the initial GET request is made to index.html and from then on, everything loads from the cache. The Cache-Control header for these requests is max-age=0, so my understanding is that the resources should not be cached. However, it seems like IIS is only checking if the requested page (index.html) has changed and not considering changes to its "sub-resources" (the images) when deciding whether to return the cached version.

As a workaround, I tried appending a query parameter to the image URLs, which forces the browser to fetch the new image. While this solution works, it feels like a workaround. I'm curious to know if there is a way to handle this situation with pure IIS configuration and its cache settings. Ideally, I would like IIS to include changes to these sub-resources in its cache invalidation check, delivering the updated images when they have changed, even if their URLs in the index.html have remained the same.

Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Is there a way to configure IIS to behave in this manner or is appending a query parameter to the URLs the best solution?

Comment: If you want caches to always check for content updates while reusing stored content, `Cache-Control: no-cache` is the directive to use. It does this by requiring caches to revalidate each request with the origin server. Note that no-cache does not mean "don't cache". no-cache allows caches to store a response but requires them to revalidate it before reuse.

Comment: Right, we are using that. Problem is (atleast we think) that the content of the file to serve will never really change. The URL to the image will always be the same but the content of the image will change. Right now it will look at the index.html and see no changes compared to the cached version.

Comment: In this case, I think the "cache busting" technique you use is important. Cache Busting works by changing the URL of the file, forcing the browser to treat it as a new file and download it from the server. You can modify the image's URL whenever the image changes. This ensures that the browser sees it as a new resource and fetches an updated version from the server. So far this seems to be the most effective way.